# Copy the visible number in a cell, not the actual number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say in A1, B1, C1 I have this.....

```
20.777 | 30.88 |   40
```

And say I want them all to have 1 decimal place, so I click the "change number of decimal places" button and get this...

```
  20.8 |  30.9 | 40.0
```

Now I want to display all three of those numbers in a single cell, in D1. The problem is I'm getting:

```
20.777 30.88 40
```

Whereas I want to get:

```
20.7 30.8 40.0
```

How do I copy over the visible number with 1 decimal place, rather than the actual number? This is the formula I'm using in D1:

```
=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: `20.777` should appear as `20.8` and `30.88` as `30.9` in your samples when you change the number of decimal places.

What you can do here is use the formula `ROUND()`:

```
=ROUND(A1,1)&" "&ROUND(B1,1)&" "&ROUND(C1,1)
```

`ROUND()` does what changing the decimal place does; anything above the digit 5 is rounded up and otherwise rounded down.

Comment: @Shonna It's okay, you can still edit your question :) Or should I do it for you?

Comment: You can if you like. I don't want to because long story short, i'm kind of confused (40 turns to 30.9....huh?).

Comment: @Shonna Now you made me confused xD What do you mean by 40 turns to 30.9?